# NoReverseMatch Error for a pattern that exists

Tags: django, url, view

I am making a simple login logout app in django. I am getting a NoReverseMatch error claiming a pattern name doesn't exist, but it does.

### My project directory looks like this:

```
dryrun_root
  -db.sqlite3
  -manage.py
  -dryrun
    -asgi.py
    -init.py
    -py_cache
    -settings.py
    -urls.py
    -wsgi.py
  -dryapp
    -admin
    -apps.py
    -init.py
    -migrations
    -models.py
    -py_cache
    -static
    -templates
      -base.html
      -dryapp
        -home.html
        -login.html
    -tests.py
    -urls.py
    -views.py
```

#### dryapp/views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dryapp/home.html'
```

#### dryapp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import HomePageView

app_name="dryapp"

urlpatterns = [
    url('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='_home'),
]
```

#### dryapp/templates/dryapp/home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Home Page</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  <h1>Home</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <small class="text-muted">
    <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}">Click here to log in</a>
  </small>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Now, this displays just fine. But the next template does not.

#### dryapp/templates/dryapp/login.html

```
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  <h1>Welcome!</h1> 
  <p>You can login here.</p>
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="border-top pt-3">
  <small class="text-muted">
    No Account? Let's Change That <a class="ml-2" href="{% url '_home' %}">Sign Up</a>
  </small>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This template will not load. I keep getting the

```
 NoReverseMatch at /login/
Reverse for _home not found. _home is not a valid view or function name.
```

I don't see what I am doing wrong from one template to the other. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you added the namespace to the included app urls.py in root urlconf? If yes then the answer given by @bmons should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the app name also in template when calling url

```
{% url 'dryapp:_home' %}
```

Comment: if it's not too much to post, would you mind explaining why the above worked and my code was failing? thank you!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls, see how django do reverse look ups